# How to add POI Android in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, apache-poi

I'd like to add [POI Android](https://github.com/SUPERCILEX/poi-android) in to Android Studio. The gradle code is this:

```
implementation "com.github.SUPERCILEX.poi-android:poi:$poiVersion"
```

But i only get this message:

```
Could not get unknown property 'poiVersion' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your project-level `build.gradle` file.

Add below code snippet:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Then, inside buildscript, add an object `ext` as below. Now, define a attribute as `poiVersion` and assign the value `3.17` to it.

This is similar to defining a variable with name as "poiVersion" and assigning value as "3.17"

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
    }

    ext {
        poiVersion = '3.17'
    }

    dependencies {
        ...
    }
}
```

And to access that variable you can use ${variable_name} as in your case, you used `$poiVersion`

Comment: But then I get this message:
 _Failed to resolve: com.github.SUPERCILEX.poi-android:poi:3.17_

Comment: @TimKlausmeyer I've updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: thanks, had added that in the buildscript and not under all projects

Answer (score 1):

$poiVersion is a placeholder. You need to replace it with a particular version

Comment: But when I do:
implementation "com.github.SUPERCILEX.poi-android:poi:3.17"
there is a nother failour:
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.SUPERCILEX.poi-android:poi:3.17.

Comment: can you please update your post and show us your build.gradle file?