# Android Gradle - Failed to resolve error when implementing Apache POI in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, apache-poi

I am trying to use the following library (https://github.com/SUPERCILEX/poi-android) so that my app can read the contents of a Word document. I have tried to follow the instructions in the accepted answer to this similar question: [How to add POI Android in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52757792/how-to-add-poi-android-in-android-studio) but to no avail. My question is different, as I have already defined the `poiVersion` variable in my project-level `build.gradle` file.

Below is the error:

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.SUPERCILEX.poi-android:poi:3.17

Below is my code (project-level `build.gradle`):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.60'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    ext {
        poiVersion = '3.17'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:1.4.93'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Below is my code (app-level `build.gradle`):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.diffchecker"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation "com.github.SUPERCILEX.poi-android:poi:$poiVersion"
}
```

Comment: try to add here `$poiVersion` smth like `1.0.0` and then you will see in suggestion the latest version of this library which you can add here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding the repository to the dependencies for the buildscript, rather than for the modules in the project.  It should be under `allprojects` - that is, this line:

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

should be moved down to this `repositories` block in the `allprojects` section of your project-level `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

That is, that block should be, in the end:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

I've confirmed that this change makes the project sync correctly in Android Studio 3.5.

Comment: Yea you are correct i misunderstood i thought org.apache.poi is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings.gradle file and add maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } in repositories section under dependencyResolutionManagement.

```
    dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing this to your build.gradle.kts

```
dependencies {
       implementation("org.apache.poi","poi","4.1.2")
 }
```